# How do I utilize the length of an array in a function (in JavaScript) when the array is being passed as a parameter and the length does not exist yet?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function-parameter

I'm trying to write a function that takes an array of strings(`strarr`) and an integer(`k`) as parameters and returns the longest string made up of `k` amount of consecutive strings within the array, not separated by commas. I need to call on `strarr.length` quite often during the function, but I keep getting an error saying that it cannot read that parameter's length.

This is my first time dealing with this issue and I have not found great internet search results for solutions. I suspect that I'm missing something very obvious. I have tried pushing the values of the `strarr` array parameter into a new array and still no luck.

So if I had `const = ['apple','pineapple','banana','strawberry']` passed as my `strarr` parameter and 2 passed as `k`, then it should return `'bananastrawberry'` because it is the longest consecutive pair of strings within the array.

```js
const arr = ['apple', 'pineapple', 'banana', 'strawberry']


function longestConsec(strarr, k) {
  if (strarr.length === 0) {
    return "";
  } else if (k > strarr.length) {
    return "";
  } else if (k <= 0) {
    return "";
  }
  let longest = "";
  let strLeng = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < strarr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + (k - 1); j > 0; j--) {
      strLeng += strarr[j].length;
    }
    if (strLeng > longest.length) {
      longest = strarr.slice(i, (i + k)).join("");
    }
  }
  return longest;
}
console.log(longestConsec(arr, 2))
```

Comment: Please show how are you exactly calling the function so that we can reproduce the error. I am getting no error running the function (but it does not work either).

Comment: What *exactly* is the error you're getting?

Comment: `for (let j = i + (k - 1); j > 0; j--) {
      console.log(i,k,j);
      strLeng += strarr[j].length;
    }` shows j===4  - that is outside the array which goes from 0 to and including 3

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you are trying to access an index that doesn't exist in you array.
A quick fix might be:

```
const arr = ['apple', 'pineapple', 'banana', 'strawberry']


function longestConsec(strarr, k) {
  if (strarr.length === 0) {
    return "";
  } else if (k > strarr.length) {
    return "";
  } else if (k <= 0) {
    return "";
  }
  let longest = "";
  let strLeng = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < strarr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + (k - 1); j > 0; j--) {
        if (j >= strarr.length) {
            break;
        }
      strLeng += strarr[j].length;
    }
    if (strLeng > longest.length) {
      longest = strarr.slice(i, (i + k)).join("");
    }
  }
  return longest;
}
console.log(longestConsec(arr, 2))
```

But I would suggest to see if there is better solution than adding a break statement.

Answer (score 0):

#### Mistakes you did

In the inner for loop, `for (let j = i + (k - 1); j > 0; j--)`, you're counting from `i + k - 1`. But what if `i` is the last index of array (`strarr.length == 10` and `i == 9`) and `k == 2`? Then your loop starts at `j = 9 + 2 - 1 = 10` and one line below, you try to do `strLeng += strarr[10].length`, but `strarr[10]` is not defined.

It also seems unnecessary to create strings before you're done finding the longest one. You could instead just remember start index of your last longest string instead.

#### How to make it better

Let's look at the requirements. For each `i` in the array, you want to merge `k` consecutive strings and keep the longest combination. From that follows:

- `i + k - 1` must never be larger than `strarr.length`. Since the `i` is the only variable here, we need to limit it by only looping up to `strarr.length - k + 1`.
- If `k == strarr.length`, there is only one string you can make - `strarr.join("")`

Finally, there's an idea that you probably do not need nested loop at all. For every `i`, you simply subtract the length of the last string in your current window and add a new one. See image:

[image]

So with that in mind, I would propose following version of your code:

```
function longestConsec(strarr, k) {
  // Cannot create any joined string with k greater than length
  if(strarr.length < k) {
      return "";
  }
  else if(k <= 0) {
      return "";
  }
  else if(strarr.length == k) {
      return strarr.join("");
  }
  let longestIndex = -1;
  let longestLength = 0;
  // length of our current group of strings
  let currentLength = 0;

  const maxLen = strarr.length;

  for(let i=0; i<maxLen; ++i) {
      // Forget the first strings length
      if(i >= k) {
        currentLength -= strarr[i-k].length;
      }
      // add the current strings length
      currentLength += strarr[i].length;
      // check if this is the largest length and save it's index
      // Only possible after processing at least k strings
      // Eg when i==1, we already went through 2 strings at this point
      if(i >= k-1) {
        if(currentLength > longestLength) {
            const startIndex = i-k+1;
            longestLength = currentLength;
            longestIndex = startIndex;
        }
      }
  }
  return strarr.slice(longestIndex, (longestIndex + k)).join("");
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle test: https://jsfiddle.net/32g5oqd1/2/